# iOS AWSS3TransferUtility Multipart in Background

Tags: amazon-s3

Does anyone know if the AWSS3TransferUtility can upload a file in parts (multi-part) - and do it in the background?

I'm looking to upload a file to AWS with multi-part support that can run in the background, but my search is coming up empty...any ideas?

Comment: Did you get the solution for this ?

Comment: @NimishaPatel no, I can see why this won't work, background upload jobs just upload a blob of data. Multi-part requires logic to get the next part, that logic has to run, but there is no-system to run it.

Comment: Did you find any other solution for background upload on s3?

Comment: Sorry no, Amazon suggested just to use their new code...which didn't do what I wanted, In the end, I just changed the way the system worked.

Comment: What did you change to get the system work? Can you please provide the steps.